# Converting to base64 adds a return character

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm trying to convert a Dictionary to a string end then Base64 it in order to save it to another string.

Here's my code

```
public class StringBase64Helper
{
    public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
    {
        var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);
    }

    public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData)
    {
        var base64EncodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
    }
}
```

and I use servicestack to serialize it

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string,object>();

dictionary.Add("VM","XX.XXXXXXXXX.Client.WPF.ViewModels.PortfolioManager");

var rr =ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(dictionary);

var str = StringBase64Helper.Base64Encode(rr);
```

The output I've is

```
eyJWTSI6IlhYLlhYWFhYWFhYWC5DbGllbnQuV1BGLlZpZXdNb2RlbHMuUG9ydGZvbGlvTWFuYWdl
ciJ9
```

Note that c1J9 is a new row, since it put's 
 character's when storing the string inside my main file.

The json from the Serializer is " 
     {"VM":"XX.XXXXXXXXX.Client.WPF.ViewModels.PortfolioManager"}"

When I decode the string I got

```
{"VM":"XX.XXXXXXXXX.Client.WPF.ViewModels.PortfolioManage
```

and after the new line I got

```
r"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note: there's something slightly odd about taking text, converting it to utf-8, then using base-64 to get text again; is this some kind of "my transport doesn't support unicode" issue?

Comment: You should use Unicode IMO. Also, why use `var` when you know it's `byte[]` (personal pet hate)

Comment: How about this : var base64EncodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData.Replace("\n",""));

Comment: About your question you're right, theres a simple reason, it's a file to persist layout. but since the customer doesn't want the data relative to viewmodel shown in clear we add such a conversion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You specified `Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks`.

If you don't want line breaks; don't ask for them!

```
public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
{
    var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}
```